# How to make a variable to indicate another object?

Tags: java

I don't have a better title for this question, you may help me change it.

```
class Example {

    class A {
        private String str;

        public String getStr() {
            return str==null ? "nothing" : str;
        }

        public void setStr(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = null;
        loadA(a);
        System.out.println(a.getStr());
    }

    private static void loadA(A a) {
        // a = ****;
        // in my project, a is load from a json string using Gson
        // Gson cannot modify a Object, it can only create a new one, say b
        // I tried to copy every field from b to a
        // but the method getStr do not always return the true str
        // so I may have to create another method "getTrueStr()" which feels bad
    }

}
```

Considered solutions and problems:

1. `a = Gson.createAnotherA()`

It doesn't work.

1. I tried to copy every field from b to a

but the method `getStr()` do not always return the true str, so I may have to create another method `getTrueStr()` which make me feel bad.

2. `clone()`

make me feel even worse.

3. `a = loadA(a)`;

this one is good. But I don't very like it. Because I have other `loadB()`, `loadC()` and they don't need this syntax, and it will look just inharmonious. If no better solution comes up, I'd choose this one.

Question is, what can I do if I choose none of my given solution.

or

If I am given a reference `A a` in a method, how can I make it the same to another Object while not using `clone()` and what I wrote above.

Comment: Do you want *one* method to load instances of `A` *and* `B`?

Comment: @LutzHorn I don't quite understand you. B??

Comment: Probably you should enunciate a question. There is no single question in your question. You just tell us about your feelings. So you want to create a copy/clone of your object of type A?

Comment: Well, I don't understand your quesiton. What would be the difference between `loadA` and `loadB`?

Comment: What do you mean with getStr() doesn't return true str? Do you mean it doesn't return a new String object with the same content?

Comment: @isnot2bad Question is, what can I do if I choose none of my given solution.

Comment: Please first tell us what you are trying to do. It is very hard to understand your question.

Comment: @bijiDango Seems I missed your question due to the missing question mark. But still your situation is unclear as you did not define your problem statement properly. Do you want to create a copy of an object? Do you want to copy the fields to an existing object of same or other type? Please update your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with this. Perfectly satisfied my need and looks nice.

class A {

```
    private A reference;

    private String name;

    public A() {
        reference = this;
    }

    public void setReference(A ref) {
        reference = ref;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        reference.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return reference.name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem really lies in your `getStr` method, which is not a real getter, it contains some logic. Is it possible to handle this outside class `A`?

As far as I understand, you want to create object `b` (of type `A`), which is copy of existing instance `a`.

Because `a` is loaded from JSON, you could just read the JSON again, which should create a new instance. I guess for some reason you cannot do this.

Instead of using JSON serializer or `clone` method (which shouldn't be used at all - it has multiple flaws), you could create a "copy-constructor":

```
class A {

    private String str;

    public A() {}

    public A(A that) {
        this.str = that.str;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str==null ? "nothing" : str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

}
```

Comment: Copy-constructor is awesome. I should have thought of it. Actually I don't want to "create object b" like you said. The fact I have to create a `b`, then make `a` somewhat a "copy" of `b`.

Comment: I thought twice, no, your solution is not capable. If I do something like `a = new A(b)`, the `a` in `main()` won't update to the new object so I can't print it.

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand. What do you mean "it won't update to the new object"? You call `new A(...)`, you assign it to `a`, so `a` is now a new instance. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I call `a = new A(...)` in the method, it won't change the `a` in `main()`.

Comment: Of course it won't. Java is `pass-by-value`, not `pass-by-reference`. `a` is the address of some object, when you pass `a` to some method, you get the value of `a`, not reference to `a`. `a` in your method is the local copy of that address, you cannot change where the outer `a` points to.