# Is it possible to update a reference in a method?

Tags: java

I have asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028643/how-to-make-a-variable-to-indicate-another-object). I will try to make this one more specific.

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = null;
        load(a);
        System.out.println(a.toString());
        // outcome is null pointer exception
    }

    private static void load(A a) {
        a = new A();
    }

}

class A {
   public void String toString() {
       return "Hello, world!"
   }
}
```

So, does it possible to update a reference in a method? For some reason I need to do this. The reasons can be seen at above linked page.

Comment: No, Java is pass-reference-by-value. You need to pass a mutable `Object`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2806564/3846058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with this. Perfectly satisfied my need and looks nice.

```
class A {

    private A reference;

    private String name;

    public A() {
        reference = this;
    }

    public void setReference(A ref) {
        reference = ref;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        reference.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return reference.name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible if you define the parameter as `A[]` i.e. `load(A[] a)` and then in the method you update the element at position 0 in that array i.e. `a[0] = new A()`. Otherwise, it's not possible as Java is pass by value. I often use this workaround.

**EXAMPLE 1:**

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A[] a = new A[1];
        a[0] = new A("outer");
        System.out.println(a[0].toString());
        load(a);
        System.out.println(a[0].toString());
    }

    private static void load(A[] a) {
        a[0] = new A("inner");
    }

}

class A {

    private String name;

    public A(String nm){
        name = nm;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "My name is: " + name;
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE 2:**

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A[] a = new A[1];
        a[0] = null; // not needed, it is null anyway 
        load(a);
        System.out.println(a[0].toString());
    }

    private static void load(A[] a) {
        a[0] = new A("inner");
    }

}

class A {

    private String name;

    public A(String nm){
        name = nm;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "My name is: " + name;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** In fact, instead of an `A[]` you can use any **wrapper object** (an object which contains in itself a reference to an `A` object). The `A[] a` is just one such example. In this case `a[0]` is that reference to an `A` object. I just think that using an `A[]` is the easiest (most straightforward) way of achieving this.

Comment: Could you please give a example? I tried your solution several times but can't make it right.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed by other java is pass-by-value.You need something like pointer in C with the object location address so that you can modify that particular address value.As an alternate to pointer you can use array.Example

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A[] aArray=new A[1];

        load(aArray);
        System.out.println(aArray[0].toString());
        // outcome is Hello, world!
    }

    private static void load(A[] aArray2) {
        aArray2[0] = new A();
    }

}

class A {
   public String toString() {
       return "Hello, world!";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = load();
}

private static A load() {
    return new A();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No you can't.**

In java everything is passed as value not as reference.

Comment: Not quite true, everything in Java is passed by value as a reference.

Comment: Will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) do? _Java is always pass-by-value. The difficult thing to understand is that Java passes objects as references and those references are passed by value._